# Premiere issue, frame freezing

Tags: premiere, video-editor, windows

I'm on the latest Adobe Premiere CC and I have a pretty solid system I think but I'm still having freezing issues when I'm editing.

```
Editing System
Windows 10 64bit
i7-5820K 6Core 3.3GHz
EVGA GeForce GTX 970 4GB SSC Gaming ACX 2.0+
16GB DDR4 Ram
512GB Samsung 950 NvME System Drive
Assets are on a Raid 0 Array of 2 5TB Drives
I have a cache drive setup on a Samsung 850 SSD
```

Everything is fine when I start but as I add effects and video to the sequence it starts to slow down to the point where I have to purge video memory occasionally or it just outright crashes. Nothing major as far as effects. I use the Lumetri color effects a lot and I use Red Giant plugins like the DeNoiser II plugin.

In fact the Denoiser plugin is pretty much useless during editing. I usually add it before rendering. It drives the render time up big time as well.

I'm open to any suggestions for upgrading this machine to make my editing smoother. I thought about adding a NAS to my network and offloading the 5tb drives to that, to archive footage not actively editing. I would then replace that raid0 with a new raid 0 with 4 ssds. Probably only 2tb for actively editing footage but it would speed the read and write speeds up dramatically.

I back everything up to cold storage drives now too.

I will say my CPU does get up to 100% when I'm watching this. I just don't see it getting maxed out on this little stuff but maybe that's the problem. I only work in 1080i5994 currently.

Hopefully I dont have to replace the system as I just bought it last year but it's really annoying trying to edit like this.

Comment: Your system should have no trouble working. I'm sure you've set up your "Project Settings" in such a way as to render and playback through your GPU.

Comment: So I will try to change that and see if it fixes it. Is the video card too weak?

Comment: No. Your system is top notch. You should be able to edit on it, no problems.